Trying to find a way to drive a ‎K101-IM2BYL02-L 10 inch 40PIN LCD through HDMI or GPIO for a Raspberry PI 3
I'm attempting a hobby project of building a small raspi based computer, I'm currently attempting to find a way to drive a ‎K101-IM2BYL02-L 10" 40PIN LCD.
I found that the Adafruit TFP401 might be able to do this (they use the same ribbon cable AWM 20624 80C 60V VW-1), but I'm a novice when it comes to this kind of hardware, so I'm unsure if the this module would be compatible as I have found mention that the pin output for displays like these are not standardized; any information on this would be appreciated.
I've had trouble finding concrete information on this display, I'll attach all information I've collected on the display below.

Resolution 1280x800/IPS
Backlight Type: LED (backlight connector: no)
Data Connector: 40 pin latch
Connector Location: Right
Interface: MIPI

I found this part number used in 'RIPAC-10P3' a 10.1" TFT Mini POS, although it mentioned it's a touch screen, unsure if this is true or if it's some attachment, the cable does support touch from what I can tell.

if there is a touch panel, then it should be attached to the front of the LCD, and have its own connector

I don't think it would be particularly easy to convert that 40 pin connector to HDMI and I don't think you want to try to do GPIO. The RPi (throughout all of its generations) has provided a MIPI DSI port on the board. However, if memory serves me correctly, that port is only a 30 pin connector, not 40.

I see; yeah and you're correct it is a 30 pin connector.
And it doesn't have the touch panel.

Would some sort of adapter be applicable, or do you think it'd be easier to directly purchase a different screen?
I've found that most portable screens for Raspberry Pi's seem to max out around 7", if you have any suggestions on a different type of portable screen around the size of 10", this would be appreciated.

@Muddykat-Tech A quick search finds this long discussion on the LCD and the Raspberry pi. It's technical and it ends talking about a respin of an adapter board. I also see that Icenowy Zheng has worked on some Feixin K101-IM2BYL02 panel drivers. But it seems a specific adapter board may be required. If so, you may need to find a touchscreen display that meets your needs (I take it the standard [and old now] 7" does not) and already has an adapter board. Not sure, though. I'm no expert on Raspberry Pi. Just did a quick search, is all.

@Muddykat-Tech Also, I'm only just now reading about displays. Appears there q43 MIPI DSI types and VESA eDP types. VESA eDP does have a 40-pin port for both touchscreen versions as well as QHD+ screens without touchscreen. (It also has a 30-pin port and a newer 50-pin port.) Are you sure you have a MIPI DSI port on that display? Finally, I did find this datasheet which does have 40-pin but I am unsure about the touch part. It does show "101" in its name. But I've no real idea if it helps.

Sadly I'm not 100% sure, I thought it'd be a MIPI DSI as the the model number for that part stated it to be so based on this product guide I found. RIPAC-10P3
I will note that the LCD in question is from an old store display, it has a driver board that attached to it, but it only played videos from a connected SD Card Slot and was unusable for anything aside from that purpose with that specific board, it's only notable inputs was a single USB, Power and SD Card Slot.

@Muddykat-Tech Well, there are plenty of sellers on aliexpress and some on ebay for that display. You might consider trolling the sites to see if any of them document the connector. Also, you might contact one (as a potential buyer) to ask about where to find docs on the display they are selling. They may help.

Will do, thank you for your assistance
